# Integer min and max values

Tags: java, types, integer

I am a newbie in programming. I was studying from a Java object programming book and performing the tutorials and examples on the book simultaneously on computer.
In the book it says that the maximum and minimum value of integers are;

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648
```

So OK. there is no problem here but;
it says that if we add 1 to the maximum value and subtract 1 from minimum;

```
class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE -1;
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE +1;

int a = min - 1;
int b = max + 1;
System.out.println("min - 1 =" + a);
System.out.println("max - 1 =" + b);
}
}
```

thus we find;

```
min - 1 = 2147483646
max + 1 = -2147483647
```

and it says that this result is because that the binary process in memory which is limited with 32 bit.
The thing that I couldn't understand. In the piece of code isn't it adding and subtracting 2 respectively from maximum and minimum values?;

```
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE -1; // subtracted 1 here
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE +1; // added 1 here

int a = min - 1;  // subtracted 1 here
int b = max + 1; // added 1 here
```

Comment: Yes it does add and subtract `2`. You have any issue understanding the output?

Comment: so the book is wrong then. it says if we subtract 1 from minimum it must be -2147483469 but it became 2147483646 cuz of that binary stuff. so the sentence "subtracting 1" is wrong in the book

Comment: I don't understand the question, nor the point of the intermediate `min` and `max` variables.

Comment: Matt. The question is clear. i could answer you better if i am not a beginner, so the point is to understand  primitive datatypes as written in the book lol. i didnt write that example

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Andrew, i read the posting rules before, and iam really sorry. it is because of my impatiance while learning new things. it wont happen again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `a` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1` and `b` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1`. So yes, it is indeed subtracting and adding 1 twice in each case. The book is not wrong, but it's a stupid way of teaching about wrap-around overflow. Just printing `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` would have made the point.

```
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE -1; // min is set to Integer.MAX_VALUE by underflow
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE +1; // max is set to Integer.MIN_VALUE by overflow
```

From the [Java Language Specification, §15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format.

The JLS is the ultimate authority when it comes to questions like this, but I don't recommend reading it as a way to learn Java. You'd be better off going through the [Java Language Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/). It's fairly comprehensive and the content is very high quality.

Comment: Thanks alot ted. i just want to learn a programming language from a resource which is good for beginners. but i really couldn't find a good one

Comment: @Geomatics - Java language books vary wildly in quality. Some are quite good, but some are just a waste of trees. I suggest going through Oracle's [Java Language Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) series.