# Java program runs slow?

Tags: java, netbeans

I don't understand why my Program need 0 second to run if there're these 2 lines in "private int ggT(int a, int b)" >>> `if (a < 0) a *= -1; if (b < 0 ) b *= -1;`

If I delete these 2 lines it needs more than 30 seconds to run.
I just want to understand what these 2 lines do, because I did'nt write the code. And I think these 2 lines are superfluous.

Btw I'm coding in Netbeans with java 8.0 I guess.

Here is the whole program:

```
public class Bruch {

    private int zaehler;
    private int nenner;
    
    public Bruch(int zaehler, int nenner){
        this.zaehler = zaehler;
        this.nenner = nenner;
        if (zaehler < 0 & nenner < 0) {
            this.nenner *= -1;
            this.zaehler *= -1;
        }
        kuerzeDich();
           
    }
           
    private int min(int a, int b) {
        if (a < b) return a;
        return b;
    }

    private int ggT(int a, int b) {
        if (a < 0) a *= -1;
        if (b <0 ) b *= -1;
    
        int ggTeiler = min(a, b);
        while (a%ggTeiler != 0 || b%ggTeiler != 0) {
           ggTeiler--;
        }
        return ggTeiler;
    }

    private void kuerzeDich() {
        int ggTeiler = ggT(zaehler, nenner);
        zaehler = zaehler / ggTeiler;
        nenner = nenner / ggTeiler;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(zaehler + "/" + nenner);
    }

    public Bruch kehrwert() {
        return new Bruch(nenner, zaehler);
    }

    public Bruch add(Bruch pOther) {
        int ggTeiler = ggT(nenner, pOther.nenner);
        int kgV = nenner * pOther.nenner / ggTeiler;
        int neuerZaehler = zaehler * (kgV/nenner) + pOther.zaehler * (kgV/pOther.nenner);
        return new Bruch(neuerZaehler, kgV);
    }

    public Bruch sub(Bruch pOther) {
        int ggTeiler = ggT(nenner, pOther.nenner);
        int kgV = nenner * pOther.nenner / ggTeiler;
        int neuerZaehler = zaehler * (kgV/nenner) - pOther.zaehler * (kgV/pOther.nenner);
        return new Bruch(neuerZaehler, kgV);
    }

    public Bruch mul(Bruch pOther) {
        int neuerzaehler = zaehler * pOther.zaehler;
        int neuernenner = nenner * pOther.nenner;
        return new Bruch(neuerzaehler, neuernenner);
    } 

    public Bruch div(Bruch pOther) {
        return new Bruch(zaehler,nenner).mul(pOther.kehrwert());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bruch b1 = new Bruch(1, 6);
        Bruch b2 = new Bruch(3, 4);
        System.out.println(b1.add(b2));
        System.out.println(b1.sub(b2));
       System.out.println(b1.mul(b2));
        System.out.println(b1.div(b2));
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (a < 0) {a = a*(-1);}` what do think this does?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: a *=-1;  is same as  `a = a*(-1)` ;  is same as `a = a multiply -1`;  obviously the values changed then the formulae will need to do more work hence it will take longer.

Comment: But the 2 lines should never be used for these numbers in the main function
because a and b are both not smaller than 0

Comment: it only checks, if its smaller than 0, it's multipied by -1 to make it positive

Comment: yes i know but it isnt smaller than 0

Comment: the program skips these lines if the numbers are 1/6 and 3/4 right?

Comment: but the numbers are never go under 0 are they?

Comment: [Trace](https://lec.inf.ethz.ch/ifmp/2019/dl/additional/handouts/ProgramTracing.html) the program and confirm it.

Comment: `1/6 - 3/4` is `-7/12` - so yes, they go negative. The way that `ggT()` is implemented it tries then (almost) all possible integer values from -7 to Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE to 1 to find the `ggT` of -7 and 12 if those two `if` statements are missing.

Comment: Yeah now i understand.
I thought the program kept jumping to the line with the while loop until it was FALSE but the program checks the whole function again until its FALSE right?

Comment: Not whole function, only the while-loop. Since it's using OR '||',both conditions must be false in order to exit the loop. If either one is true, it'll keep on looping.

Comment: i have one further question:
i put the 2 lines now into the while loop but now it take just as long as without these lines

Comment: Thats because, min(a,b) is assign to `ggTeiler`, what if it's negative? `ggTeiler--` and will do the same as I explained.

Comment: but i dont understand how the program does this >>>``It's not only checking the input, but also checks after modifying them.`` because it only runs one time the 2 lines

Comment: Oh that, you can ignore. it was just a wrong assumption.

Comment: but than, it doesnt make sense to me how the 2 lines run more than one time and change the values of a and b if they are only in a function which runs only one time

Comment: it was a small confusion.  Rather than replacing, it is creating a new instance `return new Bruch(neuerZaehler, kgV);` with modified values.

Comment: oh okay thank you for your explanations @sittsering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is when performing mathematic operations on them, it goes below `0` which are then assigned to back to `zaehler` `nenner`.
The reason it takes more time is because of this code(modulus)

```
int ggTeiler = min(a, b);
while (a%ggTeiler != 0 || b%ggTeiler != 0) {
     ggTeiler--;
}
```

`x % y` always equals `x % -y`
You can think of the sign of the second operand as being ignored.
`x % 5` (which is the same as `x % -5`).

```
-5 %  11 == -5
 5 % -11 ==  5
-5 % -11 == -5
```

Suppose one of them is `-11` and `5`.
`-11` is smaller than `5` which is then assigned to `ggTeiler`.
Now, `5 % -11 = 5` which is != 0 and the loop continues.
`ggTeiler--` -> -11-1=-12.
`5 % -12 = 5` which remains 5 all the time and the loop continues.
until `ggTeiler` it goes from minimum integer to maximum integer value. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392048/integer-min-and-max-values)
So then from maximum postive int value, it'll come to a value where both `5 % ggTeiler != 0` and `-11 % ggTeiler != 0` becomes false when `ggTeiler = -1`.

Then the loop exits.

Practice tracing your program. You'll undertand what each line does.